# Hiding Kotlin object's INSTANCE field from Java (and Kotlin)

Tags: java, kotlin, singleton, interop, kotlin-java-interop

#### Short question

Can I modify the visibility of a Kotlin object's `INSTANCE` (for Java interop) to `internal` or lower?

#### Long question

I'm writing a library and I want to have an API file / class, *written in Kotlin*, that exposes a function to be called from either Java or Kotlin like this:

Kotlin:

```
API.function()
```

Java:

```java
API.function();
```

I can achieve this by writing it like this:

Kotlin:

```
object API {
    @JvmStatic
    fun function() = TODO()
}
```

However, now I can also do this:

Java:

```java
API.INSTANCE.function();
```

I want to prevent this access to `INSTANCE` to keep my API surface to a minimum for simplicity.

Can I modify the visibility of `INSTANCE` to `internal` or lower?

It's probably not possible, because any call to `API` (from Kotlin) returns the object's instance and that should probably be hidden too for this to be possible. However, I'm curious to see if it is without major hacks.

A solution using Java would be to write `API` in Java:

```java
public final class API {
    private API() {
    }

    public static void function() {
    }
}
```

However, I'm looking for a solution written in Kotlin.

Comment: Have you considered writing interface in Java and implementation in Kotlin?

Comment: I think you didn't want an `object` (~singleton) in the first place (maybe you had a `Utilitity`-class in mind, because that's the only way to support such functions in Java? ;-)), but rather a set of functions accessible via a common interface... Linos answer shows you that and it will be wrapped to what you are comfortable with on the Java side...

Answer (score 6):

The closest I could come up with was something like this:

Create a file `API.kt` in a package `com.example.api`. Add your functions directly into that file, like this:

```
@file:JvmName("API")

package com.example.api

fun function() {
    // ...
}
```

## Kotlin:

You can import that function anywhere you need to use your api:

```
import com.example.api.function
```

Though you can't use your syntax `API.function` anymore.

## Java:

The generated class would look something like this (no singleton, just static methods, but no private constructor):

```
 public final class API {
     public static final void function() {
         // ...
     }
 }
```

Which then allows you to call it like `API.function();`

---

By specifiying `@file:JvmName("API")` you instruct kotlin to name the created class `API`.

Comment: Amazing! finally we can have fully static classes